# updating notification in android every half n hour

Tags: android

I have the code for showing the notification in the status bar. I know the updating can be done by calling `setLatestEventInfo()` again, but I want the updating to be done in every half an hour.
How do I  keep track of the time? 
Does somebody know any function for that?
I even thought of using counter which keeps getting incremented every half an hour but again retrieving the time is a problem.

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

int icon = R.drawable.index1;
CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";

long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence notificationTitle = "My notification";
CharSequence notificationText = "Hello World!";

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationAppActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, notificationTitle, notificationText, contentIntent);

final int HELLO_ID = 1;

mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
}
```

Comment: you can use the AlarmManager to be notified after 30 minutes

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and schedule recurring event every 30 minutes. Then you need to handle this event and in broadcast receiver's `onReceive()` update your notification, but usually sending `Intent` to your service to do the job.

Example code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
long recurring = (30 * 60000);  // in milliseconds
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), recurring, sender);
```

and your `MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver` is regular `BroadcastReceiver` with code in `onReceive()`. I prefer to use one broadcast receiver so I also add some additional data to the intent so my broadcast receiver knows what it should do, but you can have it separated if you like.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {

     // ... do what you need to do here...

   }
}
```

Comment: is there any simpler way to do that??

Comment: No. AlarmManager is simple and easy.

Comment: i can use AlarmManager anywhr in the program? and better set the counter within the function right?

Comment: yes, you can. But the use is pretty simple - all you need to do is to tell Alarm Manager - send me `PendingIntent` I am giving you every 30 minutes. That's it. On call and you are done unless app is killed or phone restarted.

Comment: yeah but there are so many functions under AlarmManager n i am confused about which one to us.

Comment: MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver.class should contain my code right??

Comment: Hey it works but it's not appearing in d status bar.. Before using Alarm Manager it did appear on the status bar.

Comment: Remember to add the boardcast receiver into the Android Manifest by         `<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Answer (score 0):

Use alarmManager as in example bellow:

```
AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i=new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), PERIOD, pi);
```